# How to redirect with ASP classic

Tags: asp-classic, redirect

I want to redirect from one URL to another:

```
http://female.deals.com/

http://male.deals.com/
```

How can I achieve that with the URL changing to the new URL in the browser and with a page going straight to the new URL without going to the old URL and making a refresh?

I looked through some scripts on the Internet and they didn’t work, I also don’t know ASP classic. So I am struggling to make that redirect work.

Comment: "shemale.deals.com"? Was that really necessary?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
<%
    Response.Redirect "http://www.sitename.com"
%>
```

And plus for "all" the querystrings browser url has:

```
<%
    Response.Redirect "http://www.sitename.com/?" & Request.QueryString
%>
```

Answer (score 3):

In the default.asp page that is listed as the start up page in IIS, comment out all the HTML and put in this ASP classic code:

```
<%
Response.Redirect "http://male.deals.com/"
%>
```

To keep the Query String parameters you would use this code:

```
<% response.redirect("http://male.deals.com/newpage.asp" & "?id=" & request.querystring("id")) %>
```

Another way is a ISAPI filter, [Helicon ISAPI rewrite](http://www.isapirewrite.com/).

Comment: is there also a way to take the current query string that is inside the browser url and put at the end of the url.. I want the user to be redirected to a different domain.. but that domain has the same pages as the other domain

Comment: ok, glad the version without the angle tags and percentages is an acceptable answer.