# passing session variables from asp code to C# code

Tags: c#, asp.net, vbscript, asp-classic, session-variables

I have a .asp code which I generate several session variables in it and then I redirect it to a c# doe. I am trying to read these session variables which are coming from the.asp code into my C# code, but it seems that I cannot pass those into my c# code. I can get the value of the session variables while I am still on .asp part but as soon as I redirect to c# code and try to get the session variables(and value of them), the value does not come through.

asp part:

```
response.write("Session(oldID)=&Session("oldID"))
```

c# part:

```
string oldIDSession = (string)(Session["oldID"]);
```

Comment: Think your code snippet is wrong should be `response.write("Session(oldID)=" & Session("oldID"))`. It's not important for the question mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Classic ASP web application and the ASP.NET web application (C# code) are run in separate application domains of IIS and hence the session values cannot be shared.

You can share the required data to the ASP.NET (C#) web application using query strings or making a direct post request to the C# code.

Refer [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381026/how-to-redirect-with-asp-classic) to know about passing data to C# page using query string.

Or, for posting the data using POST (in case you need to send lots of data to c# code) change the action attribute of the form in asp page to the c# (aspx page) to which the data should be posted.

**EDIT**

In the classic asp page you need to do something like ([refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209301/how-to-post-a-form-from-html-to-aspx-page)):

```
<form action="http://example.com/TestApp/YourPage.aspx" method="post">
    // form elements
</form>
```

And then, to read the posted values in your c# page you need to use ([refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2162495/getting-a-post-variable)):

```
string paramValue = Request.Form["key"]; // where key is the parameter name
```

Comment: Can you give me an example for your second method?(POST)

Comment: Thanks Bharat Gupta.

Answer (score -1):

Please refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/621549/how-to-access-session-variables-from-any-class-in-asp-net?rq=1)

I am not sure scale or nature of your application but I would suggest not to make your C# classes dependent upon session, they would be easy to test. For example.

```
//In your Asp.Net
int productId = (int)Session["productId"];

//In you c# code
public Product GetProductById(int productId){

}
```

Comment: Totally not relevant, you missed the part about Classic ASP here.

Comment: Oh! Yes, I see it now.